# Creating image from float array, index out of bounds

Tags: java, javax.imageio

Why would this method throw an index out of bounds error? Trying to create an image from data I generate myself and I expected this would work.

```
private BufferedImage getImageFromFloatArray(float[] data, int w, int h) {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    System.out.println("Image pixel array size: "
                    + ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                            .getData().length);
    System.out.println("Datasize: " + data.length);
    WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
    raster.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, data);
    return img;
}
```

Stacktrace

```
Image pixel array size: 800000
Datasize: 800000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 800000
    at java.awt.image.SampleModel.setPixels(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setPixels(Unknown Source)
    at image.PixelAraryToImageTest.getImageFromFloatArray(PixelAraryToImageTest.java:36)
```

Comment: Arent you using threads ? There cound be possibility then, that you change data array.

Comment: No I am afraid it is singlethreaded, the testcase just generates a random data array and tries to create an image.

Comment: Is it an ignorant question to ask why you are storing floats into an INT_ARGB type buffer?

Comment: @Jongware Float is 4byte data type, so does ARGB. If you want to "visualise" float data as image, you dotn have any other choice.

Comment: I've solved this in my answer below. Thanks @arynaq for your post, this was interesting.

Comment: @martin-perry: cool. Doesn't sound like a useful way of visualizing float data though .. but it'll be a cool image -- if not headache inducing.

Comment: @Jongware I agree only because its still requiring input between 0-255. If it were one normalized float for each color component I'd disagree. Thinking of color components as normalized values seems very natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Raster` width and height variables instead of the `BufferedImage` width and height variable. Also use `Raster.getMinX()` and `Raster.getMinY()`

Every value in the float array isn't a pixel value. Every value is a color component value. So a 2x1 image would actually need to be of length 4, as you have ARGB color components.  To make it a 2x1 image red for example, would require something like...

```
int numColorComponents = 4;
float[] data = new float[imgWidth*imgHeight*numColorComponents];
raster.setPixels(minX,minY, rasterWidth,rasterHeight, data);
```

Also, unlike other graphics frameworks, the float buffer here isn't a buffer of normalized values. Its value between `[0, 255]`. So, to set 2x1 image to opaque red, your buffer would be:

```
float alpha = 255;
float red = 255;   
float[] buffer = new float[]{alpha,red,0,0,alpha,red,0,0};
```

Comment: Ah yes this makes sense, I will have to decompose each sample into four components, will post update.